# How can I order my string in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

A complex question :

I've got this code (not the complete code, but the essentials for the question, I think) :

```
var $pmm:String;
var $pms:String;
var $bmm:String;
var $bms:String;

function get haute1():String { return $pmm; };
function get haute2():String { return $pms; }
function get basse1():String { return $bmm; };
function get basse2():String { return $bms; };

        accueil.todayHaute_txt.htmlText = haute1;
        accueil.todayBasse_txt.htmlText = basse1;
        accueil.todayHauteSecond_txt.htmlText = haute2;
        accueil.todayBasseSecond_txt.htmlText = basse2;
```

"haute1" is an hour (in 24h format). Something like "13h25".

It changes everyday.

Question : How can put them in ascending order in AS3 ?

Example : If haute1 = 15h20, haute2= 6h00, basse1= 11h and basse2 = 17h, the function would put them in this order : 
"`haute2`", then "`basse1`", then "`haute1`" and finally "`basse2`".

Thx

---

EDIT

I add this code that I have. is it helping you ?

```
/ Assigns hours and tidal heights
        $pmm = convdateheure($tpbs[1 + $deltapm]);
        $pms = convdateheure($tpbs[3 + $deltapm]);
        $bmm = convdateheure($tpbs[2 - $deltapm]);
        $bms = convdateheure($tpbs[4 - $deltapm]);

function convdateheure($valeur:Number):String
{
    var $heure:Number = Math.floor($valeur);
    var $minute:Number = Math.floor(Math.floor(($valeur - Math.floor($valeur)) * 100) * 0.6);

    var hoursLabel:String = "", minsLabel:String = "";

    if ($heure == 24) $heure = 0;   // Check if at the 24 hour mark, change to 0
    if ($heure < 10) hoursLabel += "0" + $heure.toString(); else hoursLabel = $heure.toString();
    if ($minute < 10) minsLabel += "0" + $minute.toString(); else minsLabel = $minute.toString();

    return hoursLabel + ":" + minsLabel; 
}
```

Comment: please convert it all to English

Comment: where are you getting the actual String values from?  Your code doesn't show that.  I see where you declare the variable.  I see a function defined for returning those variables.  I see some htmlText being set to equal those variables.  But I don't see anywhere that those variables are actually defined (as 15h20, for example... this is the important part of your code, because if those strings are created from numerical data, voila, you just need to bring that data with you into an array and sort the elements based on that value!)

Comment: I've edited my post. Let me know if it helps you

Comment: What the function you want should return? An ordered String? Or put them in order where? Into Array?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I have a dynamic textfield on my stage and I'd like to display the hours in it. Something like  `hours_txt.htmlText = //the hours in ascending order `

Comment: it's your `$valuer` value that is critical, probably.  Show us the code that this comes from.  Basically you'll push those values into an array, sort that array, and *then* convert them into your String values.  But it looks like it is that $valuer value that holds the actual numerical value.  That is what can be sorted numerically.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order some dates written in some String format:

**One way** would be, depending on you date string format, just to push them into array and sort them as strings, then read them all.

**Another way** would be to first parse those strings into `Date` instances, and push their `Date.time` property to array, sort it, then do reverse: parse all time values from sorted array into new `Date` instances then use Date.toString or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$valuer` is a numerical value:

```
var timesArray:Array = new Array();
var convertedTimesArray:Array = new Array();

function sortTimes():void{
    timesArray.push($valuer);
    timesArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
}

function convertTimes():void{
    convertedTimesArray = []; // clear the array
    for (var i:int = 0; i < timesArray.length; i++){
        var s:String = convdateheure(timesArray[i]);
        convertedTimesArray.push(s);
    }
}
```

That should give you one array of actual times, sorted in numerical order, and one array sorted in the same numerical order, but converted to String values using your function.

Comment: Thx. So I should just called the 2 functions ? `sortTimes()` and `convertTimes` ?

Comment: Better idea. Would you take a look at my code (as file) and made the change for me for 15$ (paypal) ?

Comment: what would be cool would be something like to add variables `firstOne`, `secondOne`,`thirdOne`,`fourthOne` where  `firstOne` is always = to the firsts hours of the day.

Comment: ultine@gmail.com  yeah i'll take a look

Comment: what do you mean "firstOne is always = to the firsts hours of the day"?  What are the first hours of the day exactly?  I need a better grasp of what it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: and now my edited version.  I tried to incorporate your final goal of updating the text fields as well.  See my comments in the code.